# How to make a button click quickly switch between two images in a picturebox vb

Tags: vb.net

Making a joke VB program that requires a button click to make a PictureBox very quickly switch between two pictures. I tried using the sleep command but nothing changes on screen. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TransClass2.Image = My.Resources._21
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        TransClass2.Image = My.Resources._11
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End Sub
```

TransClass2 is a class that inherits PictureBox. It's used to add transparent functionalities to PictureBoxes.

```
Public Class TransClass
    Inherits PictureBox
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(e)

        If Parent IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim index As Integer = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Me)

            For i As Integer = Parent.Controls.Count - 1 To index + 1 Step -1
                Dim c As Control = Parent.Controls(i)
                If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) AndAlso c.Visible = True Then
                    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, e.Graphics)
                    c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle)
                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top)
                    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty)
                    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top)
                    bmp.Dispose()
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is `TransClass2`?

Comment: basically a picturebox. it's just a custom class that allows me to make them actually transparent.

Comment: What means "basically"? Your question is not clear without relevant source code.

Comment: edited the post with the transclass code

Comment: Maybe you need add Application.DoEvents between altering images - Windows painting events will be processed then. Hopefully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the click handler as `Async`, then use `Await Task.Delay()`:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TransClass2.Image = My.Resources._21
    Await Task.Delay(100)
    TransClass2.Image = My.Resources._11
    Await Task.Delay(100)
End Sub
```

I think 100 might be too fast!